# Get parent element text without children's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I seem to be digging a deeper and deeper hole for myself, but I am determined to solve this now.

I am getting elements and testing to see if they have children, with the help of some very smart people here I have gotten that far. Now I need to get the parents text minus the childrens text. So below when I get information element, the text is information   credits lorem ipsum, I just need Information.

```
<ul id="navMenu">
  <li id="home"><a href="#home" rel="ajax">Home</a></li>
  <li id="information"><a href="#information" rel="ajax">Information</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#credits" rel="ajax">Credits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#lorem_ipsum" rel="ajax">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="faqs"><a href="#faqs" rel="ajax">FAQs</a></li>
  <li id="contact"><a href="#contact" rel="ajax">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jquery/javascript:

```
$('#test').load('../common.html #navMenu', function() 
{
  $.each($("#test #navMenu li"), function(i,v) 
  {
    if ($(v).find('li').length) 
    {
      var x = $(v).clone().children().remove().end().text();
      alert('This Element('+x+') has children');
    }
  });
});
```

The above script is returning empty spaces for the information element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you not just want the text of the `<a>` element?:

```
if ($(v).find('li').length) {
  $(v).find('> a').text();
}
```

Comment: That would also find the `a` elements that are children of the child `ul`. `children('a')` would work though.

Answer (score 1):

This would give information only the text 'Information'.

```
$('#test').load('../common.html #navMenu', function() 
{
  $.each($("#test #navMenu li"), function(i,v) 
  {
    var information = $(this).find('a').first().text();

    if ($(v).find('li').length) 
    {
      var x = $(v).clone().children().remove().end().text();
      alert('This Element('+x+') has children');
    }
  });
});
```

I guess you could use `$(v)` instead of `$(this)` but for readability I prefer using `$(this)`

Comment: Also works...Thank you, I like to have options and learn from different ways of doing things.